# Paypal - Return url page and variables

Tags: paypal, return, sandbox

Is it possible for me to get paypal post variables in return url. I want to show a response message in return url page depending on whether the user's transaction was completed/pending/failed one. I am testing with paypal sandbox account.

Here is my code,

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Credit Purchase">    
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo paypal_business_id;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" id="custom" value="<?php echo $user."@@@".$num_purchase;?>">  
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>buy/success">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>buy/notify
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its possible to add on `return` variable, the order id, then you get your order id when the user return and from the order id you show him the informations.

Eg

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="myReturnUrl.php?OrderID=88273882717A72734">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My requirement is to know the payment status. Just as we get the set of variables posted from paypal in notify url, will the same set of variables available in return url too? Earlier when I tried a few days ago I could get it,but now they are not getting posted to return url. I want to show the message that transaction was successful/failed in the return url page.

Comment: I got back things working correctly. The problem was because, I was clicking on the return link before the automatic redirection time of 10 seconds ends. :)

Comment: @vishnu - "I am using this but in that case i am get the product information only not get the transection id(tx_id) how i can get the txn_id by paypal." - please create a new question, I do not understand what you really ask here - or even better try to understand what I have say here - I return back the order id that I have create to locate the order...

Answer (score 4):

Wait for the IPN notification to come in, and look at the payment_status in that.
Because transactions are automatically screened for fraud, and can be funded by bank accounts, being returned to your return URL does not always equate a successful transaction.

For a list of IPN variables you can expect, see [PayPal IPN and PDT variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables)
You'll want to look (at least) at the following values:

- payment_status
- mc_gross and/or payment_gross (payment_gross is used if the transaction is in USD, mc_gross if it's any other currency)
- payment_type
- pending_reason

Comment: Yes in the success page, I check whether the payment status is completed or not.Depending on the status, I have framed a response page.Now the problem I am facing is, in Mozilla Firefox (9.0.1) once I complete the transaction , before getting redirected to return url page, the browser itself displays a message, asking for confirmation popup to continue further. If I am clickig on the "ok" button immediately then things goes fine, but if I am not doing any action the page gets redirected automatically and I am not getting any of the variables posted from paypal.

Comment: This kind of issue does not exist in Chrome and IE. Could some one tell me how could I eliminate the issue in firefox

Comment: The link above is broken and the v1 PayPal API is deprecated.

Answer (score -2):

This kind of problems does exist in FF if you wait for 10 s.
My solution is change the return url to "xxx.com?orderId=xxx".
Then you judge if it's a POST or GET. and select your order information by orderId
You don't need to worry about the status of payment. because it's should be always successful if it's returning to your store not "cancel_return"

Comment: Wow Quan, this is extremely bad and dangerous advice. You DO need to verify the payment status. You should NOT simply assume that the payment was successful because the return URL was called. You should not assume that the return was called by PayPal, you should not assume that PayPal processed the payment, and you should not include the order id in the return URL.