# PayPal: Client proceed to payment, clicked pay and got back to success page, but was not charged

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal pay button on my website, and in some cases user clicks it, redirected to the PayPal, signs in, clicks on pay button and redirected to the success page, but client account does not get charged and paypal does no call notify URL. Basically there were no transaction.

Here is the URL that user is redirected to:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?processPayment=1
&cmd=_xclick
&currency_code=USD
&no_shipping=1
&cancel_return=https://www.domain.com/cancel.php
&return=https://www.domain.com/return.php
&notify_url=https://www.domain.com/notify_url.php
&business=payments@domain.com
&receiver_email=payments@domain.com
&item_number=1
&item_name=Application+Payment
&amount=16.00
&quantity=1
&src=1
&sra=1
```

In most cases it is Mobile device with following headers: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; VS990 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.95 Mobile Safari/537.36

or

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G935V Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/78.0.0.16.67;]

Everything worked fine for a year, and that started to happen 2 days ago, and effects about 10% of the users.

Comment: This sounds like what **might** be happening, you can have users passed to return URL without a success notification if there is a processing issue.  I don't know enough to determine whether that applies here or how to mitigate it though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9053479/84206

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that notify_url does not get triggered.  So all I know that users went to paypal and lended on the success page, but no record of transaction users or my paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to double-check the transaction before offering the actual product on the success page.

You can use PDT for this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/ . It allows the website to instantly verify that digital goods and downloads are actually fully paid for, before offering them to the customer.

So when user reaches your success page, you simply make a PDT call within the same page and verify the transaction:

- If payment went through, then you can safely give them their goodies
- If payment failed, you show them an error, letting them know that the payment didn't actually go through.

Paypal actually suggests that both IPN and PDT should be used for best results, as they have different purposes and complete the same goal. Read here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/ . At the bottom, it says "If your site must be notified of payments immediately, you can implement both IPN and PDT."

Your situation is not new. I've heard of similar cases in the past. Reasons might vary, and only Paypal could give the answer for the actual reason.

Also: If you don't want to change your success page, use an intermediate redirector page that verifies it "please wait, verifying your transaction..." while making the PDT call. If PDT returns success, then redirect them to the final success page. If not, show them the error.

Comment: I understand that I need to check, and I do check with IPN (that does not get triggered at all in this case). This is how I found out about the issue. The actual problem is that users cannot pay with paypal.  it gives them success page, but nothing happens, and if they try to pay again, nothing happens again.

Comment: Well in this case your problem appears to be not the safe delivery of goods, but fixing the problem at the root. I guess the only way to address that part is to contact Paypal.

Comment: IPN ensures that you get notified when someone paid you. This is the opposite case, you don't have a transaction and this is why I suggested PDT for verification in the first place. Some documentation I've read in the past showed that it is not safe to deliver goods just on the success URL basis, without verifying it via either IPN or PDT first; as there is a chance the transaction might be not be real. However in your case it might be a different thing, like a cookie issue for example on certain models of mobile devices. Only Paypal could tell you more about the actual reason.

Answer (score 0):

I can fully confirm the same behavior, when user pays from mobile view (I tested it my self from iPhone) the transaction disappears, no IPN and no Information in both Paypal (Sender and receiver) accounts.

From Desktop Browser it works normally.

Comment: I think now everything is back to normal.

Comment: Was it paypal issue?