# Can't get Paypal and Rails app to work. Notification Paypal not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, twilio

I am building a functionality to send three MMS (via Twilio) to the phone number entered by the user in a form after receiving a payment of $1.

Story: 
1) User insert phone number and name in form. Then, click on Place order (via paypal)
2) The user go through the process on paypal-side, then is returned to my site and I receive notification of payment from paypal (the problem starts here).
3) Once I receive the completed `:payment_status`, I send the three MMS to the phone number.

**My question:**
I spent hours on this and I have no idea how to fix this. I want my [`send_text_message`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms) method to fire as soon as I receive the payment notification from paypal. I tried many things but nothing work and I start to worder if my setup is simply wrong. I need some help please.

I have one controller (Home) and two models (Home and Message).

```
# Table name: homes
#
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  phone               :string
#  sender_name         :string
#  created_at          :datetime         not null
#  updated_at          :datetime         not null

# Table name: messages
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  body       :string
#  media_url  :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
```

**MODEL -> Message**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :home

end
```

**MODEL -> Home**

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'twilio-ruby'
  has_many :messages
  validates :phone, presence: true
  validates :sender_name, presence: true
def send_text_message
    twilio_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
    twilio_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    twilio_phone_number = ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]
    sender_number = twilio_phone_number.sample

    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(twilio_sid, twilio_token)

    random_messages.each do |message|
      twilio_credentials.account.messages.create(
        :from => sender_number,
        :to => self.phone,
        :body => message[:body],
        :media_url => message[:media_url]
        )
    end
  }

serialize :notification_params, Hash

  def paypal_url(return_path)
      values = {
          business: "merchant@sumbio.com",
          cmd: "_xclick",
          upload: 1,
          return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
          invoice: id + 1000,
          amount: '1.89',
          item_name: "Game of Thrones - Funny Prank",
          item_number: '1',
          quantity: '1',
          notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
      }
      "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end

private

def random_messages
    Message.order("RANDOM()").limit(3)
end
```

**CONTROLLER: Home**

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
  before_action :set_home, only: [:show, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def new
    @home = Home.new
  end

  def create
    @home = Home.new(home_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @home.save
        format.html { redirect_to @home.paypal_url(home_path(@home)) }
        #@home.send_text_message
        #redirect_to @home, notice: 'Your Attack Has Officially Launched!'
        #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @home }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @home.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def hook
    params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
    status = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
      @home = Home.find params[:invoice]
      @home.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now
      @home.send_text_message
    end
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @home.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end

  private
    def set_home
      @home = Home.find(params[:id])
    end

    def home_params
      params.require(:home).permit(:phone, :sender_name, :plan, :notification_params, :status, :transaction_id ,:purchased_at)
    end
end
```

**------------**
**Routes**

```
resources :homes
post "/homes/:id" => "homes#show"
post "/hook" => "homes#hook"
root 'homes#new'
```

**EDIT**

The payment with paypal works. When the user click on the place order button, it redirect him to paypal and proceed to payment. The issue is that the send_text_message method is undefined and also do not get send. I can also see that the payment was made in the sandbox payment account

Comment: What's the value of running `Rails.application.secrets.app_host` in your console?

Comment: Do you receive the IPN notification?

Comment: Yes, I just can't have my send_text_message method working after the notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because the `Home` record is not found. I said I think because the OP specified that the issue is that the `send_text_message` is undefined not `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

To understand why this might be the bug, it's important to look at the `Home#paypal_url` method, as the `invoice` key is being set as `id + 1000`.

Now, in the `HomeController#hook` action, `@home` is being set to `Home.find(params[:invoice])` , which for the first record in the db would mean `Home.find(1001)`. I doubt this is the required behaviour.

Changing the `invoice` key to `id` should fix this problem.

Comment: I changed it, but now I get this error.

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 163ms (ActiveRecord: 129.8ms)

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'status' for Home.):
  app/controllers/homes_controller.rb:49:in `hook'

Comment: Yeah, based on your homes table definition above, you don't have the following colums: `status, transaction_id, purchased_at`, so those would still raise an error also. You should run a migration to add those.

Comment: Sorry, i may not know what the error is then. But I'd say you should check `Home.first.status` in case the migration hasn't run!

Comment: I am away from my computer but I will double check in a few hours. I played with this code all day and I have to admit that I may have remove those columns at some points. I will circle back soon. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oreoluwa - It worked. Thank you for the fresh pair of eyes on that one. Deeply appreciate it

Comment: Oreoluwa, Thanks for your help answering here! Can I send you a t-shirt to say thanks? Email mspeir@twilio.com for details. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you tried to make the payment directly on the phone, maybe the current problem from paypal, is the issue.

Look here: [PayPal: Client proceed to payment, clicked pay and got back to success page, but was not charged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025043/paypal-client-proceed-to-payment-clicked-pay-and-got-back-to-success-page-but)

Comment: The payment work and is being charged. Please see my edit